# VueJs 3 & InertiaJs Script Setup accessing global property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, global, inertiajs, vue-script-setup

I'm trying to set up my InertiaJs / VueJs 3 / Laravel application with a simple way to emit and listen to the events - commonly known as an event bus.

I've done some digging and have come across the [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt) package, which I've registered as a global variable on the vue instance using the following approach:

```javascript
createInertiaApp({
  resolve: (name) => {
    const page = require(`./Pages/${name}`).default;
    page.layout = page.layout || AppLayout;
    return page;
  },
  setup ({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    const emitter = mitt();

    const myApp = createApp({
      render: () => h(App, props),
    });

    myApp.config.globalProperties.$emitter = emitter;

    myApp.use(plugin).mount(el);

    emitter.on('error', (payload) => alert(payload));
  }
});
```

Now, problem I have is the fact that I'm using `<script setup>` and it doesn't seem like I don't have access to the global variables from this section.

```javascript
<script setup>

const submit = () => {
  $emitter.emit('error', 'An error occurred');
};

</script>
```

Calling `submit` method in the above example throws and error saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $emitter is not defined

I also tried using `getCurrentInstance`, but again without any luck.

Is there any way to make it work with `<script setup>` at all?

Answer (score 0):

in your script setup, use:

```
const instance= getCurrentInstance()

let emitter=instance.appContext.config.globalProperties.$emitter;

emitter.emit('error', 'an error occurred');
```